# Quasiconformal map from a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to a polytope

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds, polytopes, quasiconformal

> **Question.** Does a quasiconformal map exist between a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (such
> as a unit disc or rectangle) and a polytope?

Here, I take a polytope to be a two-dimensional surface that could be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or some other three-dimensional space, possibly $\mathbb{H}^3$.

In particular, this question interested me as it would offer a method to parameterize a permutohedron with the complex plane. The premise of this question was inspired by [Dantzig's method](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Simplex_algorithm), a numerical optimization technique in linear programming that can be realized as a path along the edge of a simplex.

By segmenting $\mathbb{R}^3$ into a series of planes and applying a Schwarz-Christoffel transform on each, I was able to form an injective map from the unit disc to polytope in three dimensions; however, I do not believe it is quasiconformal. As a secondary question, does anyone know if any such mapping could preserve the holomorphicity of a function on $\mathbb{C}$?

**Edit (Clarification):** Could it be possible to make a quasiconformal or conformal map from a disk in $\mathbb{C}$ to the following polytope?

[image: A Permutohedron as a Polytope in Three Dimensions]

Thank you.

Comment: Every piecewise linear homeomorphism (from a finite polygon) is quasiconformal.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! By piecewise linear homeomorphism from a finite polygon, do you mean a map from a polygon embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ to a polytope embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Or, do you mean a map between polygons in $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$? If I were to ask a follow-up question about purely conformal maps, would it be best practice to make a separate question?

Comment: Either one will give you a quasiconformal map. As for conformal maps: If your homeomorphism is piecewise-conformal then it is conformal.

Comment: Do you have any examples of piecewise-conformal homeomorphisms between polygons (possibly a reference in literature)? Thank you again for all of your insight.

Comment: I am not good with explicit  examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there exists a quasiconformal map (even a homeomorphism) from the Riemann sphere
to a polytope. Embedding to $R^3$ is irrelevant here, all we need is the intrinsic
metric, which is a flat metric with conic singularities. Consider a conic singularity with angle $2\pi\alpha$. Map a neighborhood of $0$ onto a neighborhood
of this point by the map which has representation in local coordinates:
$f(z)=|z|^{1-\alpha}z^\alpha$. This map is quasiconformal. Define such maps in neighborhoods of all singularities. Then extend it to the whole sphere smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I have a follow-up question, which I have posted in this entry. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389951/preserving-the-holomorphicity-of-a-complex-differentiable-form-on-a-polytope?noredirect=1&lq=1